# How To Tp Players When They Touch A Certain Block In Multiplayer

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've started making a Flood Escape (Except the flood part is magma) Map but I've started having trouble with making  people tp to spawn when they touch the magma
when there are multiple people playing. If someone could help me with this, I would be very thankful.

PS. I'm On Bedrock Edition

Answer (score 0):

Put this command in a repeating, always active, unconditional command block:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ magma 0 kill
```

This will execute the command `kill` at all players (`@a ~ ~ ~`) that have a magma block underneath them (`detect ~ ~-1 ~ magma 0`).